# Streaming a ByteArrayOutputStream to an akka http response

Tags: scala, akka-http, reactive-streams, bytearrayoutputstream, zio-streams

I'm creating a ByteArrayOutputStream using ZIO Streams i.e.:

```
lazy val byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val sink = ZSink.fromOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream).contramapChunks[String](_.flatMap(_.getBytes)
val data = ZStream.unwrap(callToFunction).run(sink)
```

This works fine - now I need to stream this data back to the client using akka http.
I can do this:

```
val arr = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray
complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, arr)
```

which works but of course the toByteArray brings the outputstream into memory i.e. I don't stream the data. I'm missing something obvious - is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert output stream to Akka Stream `Source`:

```
val byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val source = StreamConverters.asOutputStream().mapMaterializedValue(_ => byteArrayOutputStream)
```

and then simply create a chunked HTTP entity:

```
HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity.Chunked.fromData(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, source))
```

More about chunked transfer: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-4.1

For ZIO, you could probably use something like this:

```
val zSource = ZStream.fromOutputStreamWriter(os => byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(os))
```

However, you need to find a way to convert ZStream to Akka Stream Source.

Comment: https://github.com/zio/interop-reactive-streams might help with converting between ZStream and Akka Stream

Comment: Thanks @Branislav for your answer. However when I implement and run it the request never returns. I notice from the API that it's inherently blocking so I created a custom dispatcher - unfortunately again no joy. Anything that I'm missing?

Comment: @PJ Fanning - yes I looked at that, however the examples are not that great, and it uses code from reactive.org which has not been updated in years <and> the website is no longer available. Not something I'll easily be able to justify using in a corporate environment